# Storage of Objective C property variables and non property variables

Tags: objective-c, variables, object, properties, storage

Can anyone please clarify me that where exactly the variables stored in objective c ?

**In .h file**

```
@interface example: NSObject
{
  NString *string;      // where is this stored
  int     number;       // where is this stored
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSURL* mURL;  // where is this stored

@end
```

similarly,

**In .m file**

```
# import "xyz.h"

NSString *constant = @"hello";  // where is this stored

@interface example()
{
  NString *textg;      // where is this stored
  int     numb;       // where is this stored
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSURL* sURL;  // where is this stored

@end
```

Comment: FYI - Don't put ivars in the public interface (typically the .h file). Only put them in the private class extension or the `@implementation` block (which you don't show in your code).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "where is this stored?".

Comment: I meant stored on heap or stack?

Comment: They are all stored on the heap. Only local variables in a method are stored on the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"string", "textg", "number" and "numb" are instance variables to the class.  The difference is that "string" and "number" are eligible to be publicly accessible (via ref->number), and "textg" and "numb" are private (since other classes conventionally do not #import .m files).

"mURL" and "sURL" properties are stored as instance variables "_mURL" and "_sURL".  Again, "_mURL" is eligible to be publicly accessible (via ref->_mURL), and "_sURL" is not for the same reason.

And, "constant" is an ordinary global variable stored on the heap.

Comment: Good answer. To add to this answer: Instance variables or properties declared in the .m are private.

Comment: One mistake - the synthesized ivar `_mURL` for the `mURL` property will not be public and can't be accessed via `ref->_mURL`. The property is public but the ivar isn't.

Comment: One clarification - `constant` is a file global and can only be accessed from within the same .m file.

Comment: Then what is the difference between property and iVar?

Comment: @rishu1992 That topic has been covered many times. Please do some research on the topic.

Comment: A minor note: `constant` can be accessed outside the .m file with the `extern` keyword.

Comment: Okay Thank you. May I know what is the difference between string and mUrl that I have declared. mUrl can be accessed publicly.But not the string. Then what is the difference in having iVar in .h file and iVar in .m file. Also what is the use of declaring property privately in .m file?

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> where exactly the variables stored

To answer just this: all the variables other than `constant`, and the variables used by the properties, are stored as part of the memory allocation for each instance of your class `example` that you create. Every instance has its own copy of each variable. E.g. when you do:

```
example *anExample = [example new];
```

You are requesting that an instance of `example` is created and a reference to it is stored in `anExample`. That instance contains the all the instance variables and properties you have declared (and it also contains any instance variables and properties for its superclasses, in this just just `NSObject`).

Your other variable, `constant`, is declared at the file level. Such variables are stored along with the compiled code in your file as part of your application. Regardless of how many instances of your class are created there is only ever one `constant` variable. Methods running on behalf of any instance all see the same `constant` variable.

HTH

Comment: Okay Thank you. May I know what is the difference between string and mUrl that I have declared. mUrl can be accessed publicly.But not the string. Then what is the difference in having iVar in .h file and iVar in .m file. Also what is the use of declaring property privately in .m file?

Comment: @rishu1992 - That's a few different questions and you'll find answers to them all on SO. Why not search and ask another question if you don't understand something? To get you going, by default anything in the .h is publicly accessible, anything only in the .m not. A private property is like a private method - for use by the class itself.