# difference between public ivar and private proprety in objective c

Tags: objective-c, properties, ivar

May I know what is the difference between instance variable in **.h** file and property in **.m** file in objective c?

I know that both cannot be used outside the class. Any other difference?

Comment: Please check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Public instance variables can very well be used outside the class (I'm not saying they should be defined, though).

Comment: You've just asked a similar question in comments to [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773335/storage-of-objective-c-property-variables-and-non-property-variables/27773665). What did you read that made you decide that instance variables in the `.h` *cannot* be used outside of the class contrary to what you were told in the answers to your previous question? Provide the reference and maybe someone can explain it to you.

Answer (score 1):

A. You can add ivars inside the implementation, too:

```
@implementation AClass
{
   id ivar;
}
```

Therefore the difference is not that ivars has to be in the header (interface). (But see below B.)

B. If an ivar should not be used outside, there is no reason to put it in the public header. Why do you want to inform somebody about an ivar, if he cannot use it? This is source code spamming.

C. A property adds (or uses) an ivar. Additionally it adds accessor methods.

D. A property provides additional semantic information, especially about atomicity and setter semantics, if it is declared in the header.

Up to here it should be clear that properties are usually the better way to model an object state. So why do we have ivars in headers?

This is for legacy. In former times we did not have declared properties. There has been some reasons for having ivars in the header (for example to tell the compiler the object size), but this are gone. The only meaning for declaring ivars in the header in nowadays is that you make them public and let others access them directly for performance reasons. You should have very good performance reasons to do so. I had never had them.

In addition to Jef's answer:

If you want to make ivars public to subclasses, you can put them into a class continuation in an extra file. Let's have an example:

MyClass.h

```
// We do not put ivars in the public header. This is an implementation detail.
@interface MyClass : NSObject
…
@end
```

MyClass_SubclassAddition

```
// We do put ivars in an extra header with a class continuation, to make them visible for subclasses
@interface MyClass()
{
  id ivar;
}
@end
```

MyClass.m or MySubclass.m

```
// We use both headers in the implementation and subclass implementation:
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClass_SubclassAddition.h

@implementation MyClass
…
@end
```

You can get rid of the "subclass ivar problem", if you use setters in initializers. Whether this is wrong or not to do so, is a different discussion. Personally I prefer to use setters. But do not let us start that discussion again (and again and again …)

Answer (score -1):

the biggest practical difference is that subclasses can see and use ivars which are declared in the .h, where if they are in an extension at top of the implementation file a subclass cannot access them.
I like to start with them in the .m file but i'll happily move one to the header in order to use it from a subclass.

Comment: You can get effect better by far with an extra class continuation.

Comment: 'by far' is questionable.  Your answer is very good and i upvote you.  But mine is not inaccurate, the question is about the difference, not the best practices..

Comment: I did not say and do not think that your answer is incorrect. I did not down vote it.